# js.erb rendering only the ruby code, not the js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, multipartform-data, multipart, net-http

**Edit: I solved the problem myself - see below**

I have a form where I upload images using the add_picture_to_project_path route included in my projects_controller.rb. This method is exectuing the file upload in the model and then returning some Json to my controller. Once this is done I want to render the add_picture_to_project.js.erb file but I have the following issue. There is only the ruby code that is working, the javascript is not responding at all.

**routes.rb**

```rb
patch '/addLocalPicture', to: 'projects#add_picture_to_project', as: :add_picture_to_project
```

**show.html.haml**

```rb
= bootstrap_form_tag(url: add_picture_to_project_path,method: :patch, html: { :multipart => true }) do |f|
      .form-group    
        %input{type:'file', multiple: true, name:"picture", id:"fileupload"}
        = hidden_field_tag 'stock_id', "5da481f45d5f4443c644f89f"
        = hidden_field_tag 'project_id', @project._id
        = hidden_field_tag 'company_id', @company._id
        = f.submit("Valider", class: 'simple-btn')
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```rb
       def add_picture_to_project
       picture_params = {
                stock_id: params[:stock_id],
                project_id: params[:project_id],
                company_id: params[:company_id],
            }
       @picture = Picture.upload_picture(params[:picture], picture_params, bearer_token)
```

**model:  picture.rb**

```rb
def self.upload_picture tempfile, picture_params, bearer_token
        params = {
                "photoUploadS3" => UploadIO.new(File.open(tempfile.path), MIME::Types.type_for(tempfile.path), File.basename(tempfile.path)), 
                "stock_id" => picture_params[:stock_id], 
                "project_id" => picture_params[:project_id], 
                "company_id" => picture_params[:company_id], 
                "filename" => File.basename(tempfile.path), 
                "size" => File.size(tempfile.path)
            } 

        # Create the HTTP objects
        uri = URI("#{ENV['API_HOST']}/pictures/addLocalPicture")                       
        req = Net::HTTP::Post::Multipart.new uri.path, params

        req.add_field("Authorization", "Bearer #{bearer_token}") #add to Headers
        res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port) do |http|
            res = http.request(req)
            response =  eval(encode_utf8(res.body))                  
            return response.to_struct       
        end                                               
    end
```

This is rendering the add_picture_to_project.js.erb which is only executing the ruby content... Maybe it is because of the file names ?

**add_picture_to_project.js.erb**

```
console.log("hello");
<%= say "hello #{@picture}" %>
```

In my terminal I get

```rb
Rendering projects/add_picture_to_project.js.erb
 ______________________________________ 
/ "hello #<OpenStruct                  \
| stock_id=\"5da43c644f89f\ |
| ",                                   |
| project_id=\"5da0c75300c |
| a\",                                 |
| company_id=\"5caddb3d127 |
| 3\",                                 |
| filename=\"RackMultipart20191105-536 |
| 84-1um4lsk.jpg\", size=412324,       |
| unique_filename=\"ff3f2720-001a-11ea |
| -8828-01b6885e7183-RackMultipart2019 |
| 1105-53684-1um4lsk.jpg\",            |
| created_at=\"2019-11-05T22:24:13.926 |
| Z\",                                 |
| updated_at=\"2019-11-05T22:24:13.926 |
| Z\", status=1,                       |
| user_id=\"5d9f3817602ef027\" |
| ,                                    |
| projects=[\"5300ca |
\ \"]>"                                /
 -------------------------------------- 

  Rendered projects/add_picture_to_project.js.erb
```

What should I change to have my javascript executed?

**Answer:** 
My issue was in the picture.js file - I had my datatype set to Json when it should be 'script'. This fix my issue. I leave my question here so that people can have more information on how to setup net http multipart file upload with the jquery file uploader.

```js
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'script',
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: How are you doing the request? show the form declaration, show the logs too. You say something about json but then js? did you check the network tab on the browser to inspect the actual request response?

Comment: Where is the form?

Comment: Thanks for you help ! I fixed my error. I had my datatype set to JSON when it was a Script I was calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** 
My issue was in the picture.js file - I had my datatype set to Json when it should be 'script'. This fix my issue. I leave my question here so that people can have more information on how to setup net http multipart file upload with the jquery file uploader.

```js
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'script',
        done: function (e, data) {
            console.log(data);
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo(document.body);
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your controller action includes a `respond_to` block which lets the app know how to handle the request format:

```rb
def add_picture_to_project
  picture_params = {
    stock_id: params[:stock_id],
    project_id: params[:project_id],
    company_id: params[:company_id],
   }
  @picture = Picture.upload_picture(params[:picture], picture_params, bearer_token)

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```